# Twitter-text.js outputting html as plain text

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have successfully used twitter-text.js to convert tweets containing links into clickable HTML before, but cannot get it to work as expected on this deployment. I am calling it as before:

```
twitterdata.results[i].text = twttr.txt.autoLink(twitterdata.results[i].text);
```

where `twitterdata.results` is an array of results from my API call.

The original tweet in 'view source' without using Twitter-text.js would look like:

```
Wow what a great day here are some photos: Click http://www.google.com
```

Using Twitter-text.js it inserts the correct `< a href>` etc, but then it displays as plain text like :

```
Wow what a great day here are some photos: Click <a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow" >http://www.google.com</a>
```

and the links are not clickable, as if it is ignoring the HTML elements.

What could be stopping it from working? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any other code on the page? Is the text being parsed any other way? It looks like the characters are being escaped so that they aren't seen as code by the browser. Do you have an example of this live somewhere we can look at?

Comment: Thanks, it was an issue with Twig and jQuery Templates.

Comment: Don't you love it when you figure it out?

Comment: yeah, sometimes just typing out the issue makes the solution more obvious.

Comment: Can't tell you how many times I've solved a problem just by trying to type out the question in a way that made sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sovled.

Issue was as expected , html coming in plaintext. Using Twig templates meant Jquery Template couldn't escape properly.

```
{% raw %}
    {{html text}}
{% endraw %}
```

The `{% raw %}` escapes the Twig and the `{{ html }}` changes the input in the jQuery Template  as needed.